# Colspan with incorrect rows don't render correctly

Tags: html, html-table

http://jsfiddle.net/9p7Mx/1/

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find the correct search terms:

If you have an HTML table such as:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The colspan=3 on the last row will not actually line up correctly because you don't actually have 4 td elements. If you look at my example link, I have two tables, one with two tds with colspan=2 and the last with four actual tds. In the first, the td elements are just mimicking 4 tds with their own colspan=2 and thus I assume the table has no way of knowing exactly how large a single colspan is since there is none. Without knowing the exact with on a single colspan, it appears the table doesn't know what to do.

If I can't change the number of td elements in the table, is it possible to get the same effect? I'd rather not assign a width using CSS, and assigning a width WILL work (tested) but I'd like to see if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup violates the HTML table model, as http://validator.w3.org tells if you use it in HTML5 mode (“Table column 2 established by element td has no cells beginning in it.”). So you should expect inconsistent and unexpected rendering.

If your table logically has just three columns, make it so. Instead of trying to make some columns wider by using `colspan`, use CSS to set the widths. The `colspan=2` attribute means just that the cell spans two columns. And you cannot validly span a column that does not exist.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Using classes and setting the width for the X% you want.
You must consider some divs instead of a table.